# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mediawiki, pywikibot

I installed `pywikibot-core` (version 2.0b3) for my Mediawiki installation. I got an error when i tried to run a command which contains Unicode text.

I run the following command:

```
python pwb.py replace.py -regex -start:! "\[মুয়ায্যম হুসায়ন খান\]" "[মুয়ায্‌যম হুসায়ন খান]"  -summary:"fix: মুয়ায্যম > মুয়ায্‌যম"
```

Here is the error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwb.py", line 161, in <module>
    import pywikibot  # noqa
  File "/var/www/html/banglapedia_bn/core/pywikibot/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pywikibot import config2 as config
  File "/var/www/html/banglapedia_bn/core/pywikibot/config2.py", line 285, in <module>
    if arg.startswith("-verbose") or arg == "-v":
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `python3` instead of `python`.

---

You are seeing that error because the module `config2.py` uses `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, making all strings in the module unicode objects. However, `sys.args` is a bytestring, and is not affected by `__future__` imports.

Therefore, because `arg` is a byte string, but `"-verbose"` and `"-v"` are two unicode strings, `arg` gets implicitly promoted to unicode, but this is failing because implicit conversion only works with ASCII.

Instead, in Python 3, all strings are unicode by default, including `sys.args`.

Comment: thanks, it solved the issue. But previously i used the Compat branch of PyWikipedia and the `python` worked perfectly and now it requires `python3`. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @nasirkhan: I don't know anything about PyWikipedia, sorry. In order to answer this question, I just downloaded the source code. So, either give me a link to the "Compact branch", or ask the developers of PyWikipedia (possibly giving them the link to this question, so that they are aware of the issue).